Man\teenager has a old sounder recorder and end up playing at a DJ event\concert
this movie annoys me because I cant remember that title, hope you can help.
this guys has a old sound recorder something like the below image.
he goes around recording sounds he likes, and what I remember he records crickets chirpping and ends up at a dj event and something goes wrong with the sound systems (i think) and he hooks up his device and starts playing sounds by the crickets and slows the sound down and it sounds awesome and people love it.
thats all i remember of the movie, its drives me nuts!
I watched this movie maybe in the 90s around-about


Sounds like the Australian film One Perfect Day, but it's from 2004.

Tommy Matisse is a gifted musician studying at London's Royal Academy of Music, where he is striving to write a brilliant new operatic song called "One Perfect Day" in conjunction with his girlfriend Alysse back in Australia. [...] Tommy undertakes an odyssey of self-discovery and tragedy in Melbourne's dance music scene.

He's also a DJ. Here's the scene where he slows down cricket sounds (which was most likely inspired by a semi-true phenomenon discovered in 1992):



